# How to find linux equivalent of solaris specific header files?

Tags: linux, migration, solaris, porting

I porting a Solaris application to Linux platform, I am looking for the alternative header files of the following Solaris specific files.

```
sys/devpoll.h

sys/procset.h

sys/systeminfo.h

sys/types32.h

sysutil.h
```

Answer (score 1):

You have yourself some serious rewriting to do as your application appears to be using a significant amount of Solaris-specific and even Solaris internal implementations.

`sys/devpoll.h` - no equivalent, the closest Linux replacement for Solaris `/dev/poll` is to use [`sys/epoll.h`](http://linux.die.net/man/4/epoll).

`sys/procset.h` - no equivalent, almost entirely Solaris kernel internels.

`sys/systeminfo.h` - `sys/sysinfo.h`.  See the `sysinfo()` man page for both Solaris and Linux as the `sysinfo()` library call is significantly different on the two platforms,

`sys/types32.h` - no equivalent.  Not only that, the `sys/types32.h` on my Solaris 11.2 file server has this warning:

```
/*
 * Interoperability types for programs. Used for:
 *
 * Crossing between 32-bit and 64-bit domains.
 *
 * On disk data formats such as filesystem meta data
 * and disk label.
 *
 * Note: Applications should never include this
 *       header file.
 */
```

`sysutil.h` - Does not appear to be a Solaris header.  It does not exist on my Solaris 11.2 file server, nor does it appear in the OpenSolaris source hosted at [illumos.org](https://www.illumos.org/search/).